# Send and receive for loop for a python3 generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a generator that is actually a function that recursively resolve external document references. Say some XML with some href tags.

I've made a generator that returns a URL and expects the content of the url to be sent back into the generator. For example I can use it like this:

```
def http_fetch_content(url):
    """ A function that returns the body of a HTTP GET request to the URL """
    (...)

resolver = resolver_generator(base_document)

try:
    url = next(resolver)
    while True:
        resolver.send(http_fetch_content(url))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

My question is: Is there any easier way to use this generator? Something like the way you would use a output only generator in a for loop. Something like:

```
for url in resolver(base_document):
    yield http_fetch_content(url)
```

Anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that: have a generator that yields and object; the client can modify the object and right after the yield the generator will have access to the modified object.

However, this goes against the idea behind the generator and you are making it both awkward and unreadable. Instead you should loop over your urls and call fetch_content, thus creating a list of contents. It is actually a one-liner:

```
contents = [http_fetch_content(url) for url in resolver(base_document)]
```

Comment: But those external URLs can themselves have external references. I want recursive resolving

Comment: You are risking a recursion that does not stop until it resolves all of the internet. I am not sure how and what you want to milk from recursive resolving, but a generator is probably not the best tool for this. There are other powerful constructs, like recursive method invocation, etc.